# Can matplotlib plot a time-event bar?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there any method in matplotlib to plot a time-event bar like the following?

[image]

Searched around the manual but didn't find an elegant method.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this by writing a new function that does this by drawing rectangular filled polygons.

Comment: using `barh` creatively is probably an easier route